# Call external API with Cloud Function and create document

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to create some cloud functions to:

1. call Google Directions API using Axios
2. create a document at Firestore based on the API result
3. Return the document reference to my iOS App.
   (I'm on Blaze plan, pay as you go)

I'm having trouble to create the following functions as my Node / JS knowledge is very basic.
Could someone please have a quick a look and let me know what I'm missing?

Obs.:
The code is deploying to firebase with no warnings and erros. I'm pretty sure that the problem is the way that I'm trying to return my callbacks.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I've made a few changes on the code, but I'm still receiving nil on my iOS App.
The code is still not creating a document on firestore.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const axios = require('axios');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


// Func called by iOS App, If user is auth, call google maps api and use response to create a document at firestore
exports.getDistanceAndSavePackage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth){ return {status: 'error', code: 401, message: 'Not signed in'} }
  const userId = context.auth.uid;
  const startCoordinates = data.startCoords;
  const endCoordinates = data.endCoords;

  const pkgDocReference = getGoogleRoute(startCoordinates, endCoordinates, res => {  
    console.log('google cloud function has returned');
    let venueId = userId;
    let distance = res.distance.value;
    let resultStartAdd = res.start_address;
    let resultEndAdd = res.end_address;

    const pkgDocRef = createTempPackage(venueId, distance, resultStartAdd, resultEndAdd, resultPkg => {
      return resultPkg
    })
    return pkgDocRef;
  })
  return pkgDocReference;
});



//Create Package Document
function createTempPackage(venueId, distance, startingAddress, endingAddress, callback){
  console.log('Creating temp package');
  const docRef = admin.firestore().doc(`/temp_packages/`)
  docRef.set({ 
    id: docRef.id,
    venue_id: venueId,
    distance: distance,
    starting_address: startingAddress,
    ending_address: endingAddress,
    timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    status: 0
  })
  .then(docRef => {
    console.log('Doc created')
    return callback(docRef);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('Error trying to create document')
    return callback(error);
  })
}


  //Call Google directions API
  function getGoogleRoute(startCoords, endCoords, callback){
    axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json',
      params: {
          origin: startCoords,
          destination: endCoords,
          key: 'mykey'
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
          let legs = response.data.routes[0].legs[0];
          return callback(legs);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Failed calling directions API');
            return callback(new Error("Error getting google directions"))
        })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a HTTPS trigger you'd need to `return {status: 'OK', code: 200, data: json}`.

So that it would actually respond through the web-server.

Comment: Hey Martin, OP seems to be creating a [HTTPs **Callable** endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), for which you can just return the JSON data to return to the caller.

Comment: Hey Martin and Frank, I tried to edit the code and made a few changes based on examples and your answers but I still couldn't figure out what's going on. I'm receiving nil on the callback from my iOS app and the code is still not creating the document on firestore.

Comment: I've just had a look; this has to be `data` and not `message`, as the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#response_body) shows... so that the client will receive the format it expects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is final solution, however there is an error in the code:

`const docRef = admin.firestore().doc('/temp_packages/')`

This statement should trow error:

`Value for argument "documentPath" must point to a document, but was "${documentPath}". Your path does not contain an even number of components.`

The error is thrown before `docRef.set` so it will not be taken into consideration in `catch` statement. I was trying to test it, but all my tries finished with this error. Maybe this error is somewhere in your logs.

I hope it will help!